# Variables in templates w/o PHP enabled

Tags: ee2, templates, variable

I have a problem where I need to increment a variable if it satisfies a conditional like so:

```
{matrix_tag_pair}
  {if matrix_column_name}
    $increment++
  {/if}

  {if $increment > 9}
    do this...
  {if:else}
    do that...
  {/if}
{/matrix_tag_pair}
```

Is it possible to do this without enabling PHP in a template? I don't see where you can create throwaway variables like counters using just EE template tags.

**Solution:**
[Increment](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/increment) was close enough that I modified the source so it could also return the count without incrementing.

```
{exp:pvl_increment start="0" step="1"}
{matrix_tag_pair}
  {if matrix_column_name}
    {exp:pvl_increment random}
  {/if}

  {if {exp:pvl_increment increment="no" random} > 9}
    do this...
  {if:else}
    do that...
  {/if}
{/matrix_tag_pair}
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This was enough that I didn't have to enable PHP in my template. This slightly modified version of Increment combined with [Loop Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/loop-plus) could be a very useful combination.

Comment: If anybody also thinks this is useful, I've got the forked addon source over at https://github.com/ginghamsburg/Pvl_increment

I've submitted a pull request to the author to roll it into the next version.

Comment: Push merged. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but perhaps the [Increment](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/increment) plugin could do what you need? Or at least provide a basis for development. At the moment it always returns the current increment value, but it would be pretty easy to add a param to surpress this. Shout if you need help with that.

You would then do something like:

```
{matrix_tag_pair}
  {if matrix_column_name}
    {!--contains pseudocode! supress_output param doesn't exist in linked plugin as is, but could easily be added--}
    {exp:pvl_increment random id="my_id" supress_output="yes"}
  {/if}

  {if {exp:pvl_increment id="my_id"} > 10}
    do this...
  {if:else}
    do that...
  {/if}
{/matrix_tag_pair}
```